# RxJS catchError operator does not catch an error on an observable created from a Promise

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, ionic4

I am building an ionic 4 / angular 8 app using rxjs 6.5.1.

Here I have a Promise that is converted to an observable that is used further down the pipe in order to download a file via a file plugin for ionic. As seen at the bottom of the code, I create an array of observables, which will be subscribed to in case  `someFlag` is set. The issue with this code is that at the point of pushing the observables to the array, the code in `getLocationForFile(fileName)` gets executed and I get the following error in the console:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FileError: {"code":12,"message":"PATH_EXISTS_ERR"}`. Such error is perfectly fine to happen in case the path exists. The problem is that this error is not caught in the catchError operator of the `getLocationForFile` method. The interesting part is that in case `someFlag` is set, the forkJoin will be triggered and the very same error will be then caught in the catchError in getLocationForFile(fileName), but the error of uncaught promise error will still be there.

```
private createDirectory(dirName) {
    return from(this.file.createDir(path, dirName))
}

public getLocationForFile(fileName: string) {
    return  this.createDir().pipe(
      switchMap(dirEntry => of(dirEntry.nativeURL + fileName)),
      catchError(_ => of(""))
    )
}

public downloadFile(fileName) {
    return this.getLocationForFile(fileName).pipe(
        switchMap(fileLocation => return this.file.downloadFile(url, {}, {}, fileName)),
        catchError(error => of(handleError(error));
    )
}

let filesToDownload = [];

for(let fileName of fileNames) {
    filesToDownload.push(downloadFile(fileName))
}

if(someFlag){
    forkJoin(filesToDownload).subscribe(results => {
        handleResults(results)
    })
}
```

In case I rewrite the `createDirectory(dirName)` like this

```
private createDirectory(dirName) {
    return from(this.file.createDir(path, dirName)
    .then(result => of(result))
    .catch(error => throwError(error))
    )
}
```

then the error is handled and I do not get the Uncaugh in promise error.

So one question is why the catchError in the `createDirectory` method does not catch the error that occurs when I push the observable to the array and the other one is how to fix it (I do not want to use the workaround from the last code snippet).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe that's because you're already handling the error with `catch()` which you don't need anyway because rejected Promise will be turned to `error` notification inside `from`. The same applies to the `then()` handler you have.

Comment: The `catch()` is actually the workaround. The thing is that I am then handling the promise, which the `from` operator should naturally do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe fix your promise code first will solve your problem

there is no need to catch, let the error flow through

```
private createDirectory(dirName) {
    return defer(()=>this.file.createDir(path, dirName))
}
```

Comment: `private createDirectory(dirName) {
    return from(this.file.createDir(path, dirName)
    .then(result => of(result))
    .catch(error => throwError(error))
    )
}`
is actually what fixes the problem. If I do not have it an let the error pass the flow, the catchError does not catch the error.

Comment: did you check your network tab and see every forkjoin request went through? also by saying it is  *not catching error* means you can't see the error in catchError or in subscribe error handler ?

Comment: The error occurs when forkJoin is not executed. In some cases this will be the case based on the value of `someFlag`.

Comment: maybe as the name suggest, the promise error is uncaught in promise chain but in fact it is caught by observable. You should log the observable error object and see if this is the case

Comment: I added logs to  both switchMap and catchError and none of them gets called.

Comment: that's wierd. you can try produce a simple stackbliz

Comment: here I have two stackblitz apps - one with Angular and one plain RxJS. Both contain the same code, but the behaviour is different. Check the console.


Angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mltgh3
RxJS: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ecvnsv?devtoolsheight=60

To see what problem I have, just comment/uncomment the forkJoin in the run() method

Comment: angular one is empty starter files. The rxjs one works as expected though. You did catch the error in catchError no?

Comment: Wrong copy/paste. Here is the proper link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnnczt

Comment: I see why now. change to defer() , from will execute immediately. updated the answer

Comment: That works, you are right. The thing that bothers me is why the error is not caught even when the observable is created before anyone subscribed

Comment: glad it helps. please accept the answer if you find it correct.